# How to use dynamic table rowspan in vue.js?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I want to make that table in example photo.

[image]

I want to connect with row using by rowspan and made codes.
But it didn't work, and browser displayed an error occurred.
first of all, my sample data is below.

```
    export const dummyCssTest = [
    {
        id:"1",
        name:"a",
        sub:[
            {id:"1#1",name:"b"},
            {id:"1#2",name:"c"},
        ]
    },
    {
        id:"2",
        name:"d",
        sub:[
            {id:"2#1",name:"e"},
            {id:"2#2",name:"f"},
            {id:"2#3",name:"g"},
        ]
    }
]
```

if sub's id includes same number as main's id like "1", "2" in that case,
name's row connect with number of sub's array length.
So I made code below.
My code is written by TypeScript and framework is Nuxt.js and Vuetify.js.
Could you advise me, please?

```
    <template>
  <div>
      <v-simple-table dense>
          <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="blue lighten-5">name</th>
                <th class="blue lighten-5">sub_name</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
                  <td :rowspan="[sub.length]">{{item.name}}</td>
                  <td>{{item.sub[sub.length].name}}</td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </v-simple-table>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue} from 'nuxt-property-decorator'
import { dummyCssTest } from "~/store/dummy";

@Component({})
export default class extends Vue{
    items:any=[]
    mounted(){
        this.items = dummyCssTest
    }
}
</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>

</style
```

> 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a row for every sub item, not just every item, and this means 2 loops instead of 1.  There are also some logical and syntax errors in your loop and in the implementation of `v-simple-table`.

The loop should look like this:

```html
<template v-for="item in items">
   <tr v-for="(subitem, iSub) in item.sub" :key="subitem.id">
      <td v-if="iSub === 0" :rowspan="item.sub.length">{{ item.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ subitem.name }}</td>
   </tr>
</template>
```

A row is made for each subitem, and if it's the first subitem, a rowspan cell is created. Here is a full demo:

```js
const dummyCssTest = [
    {
        id:"1",
        name:"a",
        sub:[
            {id:"1#1",name:"b"},
            {id:"1#2",name:"c"},
        ]
    },
    {
        id:"2",
        name:"d",
        sub:[
            {id:"2#1",name:"e"},
            {id:"2#2",name:"f"},
            {id:"2#3",name:"g"},
        ]
    }
];
    
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      items: dummyCssTest
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.s {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.3.15/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app">
  <v-simple-table dense>
    <template v-slot:default>
      <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="blue lighten-5">name</th>
            <th class="blue lighten-5">sub_name</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <template v-for="item in items">
            <tr v-for="(subitem, iSub) in item.sub" :key="subitem.id">
              <td v-if="iSub === 0" :rowspan="item.sub.length" class="s">{{ item.name }}</td>
              <td>{{ subitem.name }}</td>
            </tr>
          </template>
      </tbody>
    </template>
  </v-simple-table>
</div>
```